Elasticsearch How to exclude indices when using Java Api Client
Elk-Stack Version: 8.7.1
Java Api Client: 8.13.1
When executing a search I want to search over all indices excluding all indices that start with a dot.
According to the regular Elasticsearch Api you put *,-.* in the path.
When I use the withJson functionality of the Java Api Client I dont have the possibility to define the path with indices, I have just the index-Method.
So how can I exclude these indices ?
Reader queryJson = new StringReader("{\n" +
                    "  \"_source\": {\n" +
                    "    \"excludes\": [ \"@timestamp\", \"@version\" ]\n" +
                    "  },\n" +
                    "  \"size\": 500,\n" +
                    "  \"query\": {\n" +
                    "    \"multi_match\": {\n" +
                    "      \"query\": \"Beratung\",\n" +
                    "      \"fields\": [\"*\"]\n" +
                    "    }\n" +
                    "  }\n" +
                    "}");

            SearchRequest request = SearchRequest.of(b -> b.withJson(queryJson).index("_all"));
            SearchResponse<Object> response = esClient.search(request, Object.class);

I tried passing "", "-." to the index method without success.

The method you tried GET *,-.*/_search is make sense. If it's not working you can use elasticsearch alias to search all indices at once. Add the alias to all indices you prefer to search.
Note: If your application create daily/monthly indices you can automate this process by adding alias into the index templates.
#add alias to some index pattern or all of them one by one
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "test-*",
        "alias": "all_indices"
      }
    }
  ]
}

#check if it's added
GET _cat/indices/all_indices?v

#search with alias!
GET all_indices/_search


